# Upload and Download Php MySQL Script

Tags: php, mysql, file, upload, download

I've made use of a script which is available online. The File upload.php allows the user to upload a file and then store the selected file in the MySQL database. Later the download.php script displays the links for all the files stored in the database. When the user clicks the link, the file should be downloaded. I've enclosed the script below. But the problem is, when I click the link the content of the file gets displayed instead of getting downloaded.

### upload.php

```
<!--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `upload` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `size` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content` longblob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;


-->
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table width="350" border="0" cellpadding="1"
                   cellspacing="1" class="box">
                <tr>
                    <td>please select a file</td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"
                               value="16000000">
                        <input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile"> 
                    </td>
                    <td width="80"><input name="upload"
                                          type="submit" class="box" id="upload" value=" Upload "></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0) {
    $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $tmpName = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
    $fileType = (get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 0 ? mysql_real_escape_string(
                            $_FILES['userfile']['type']) : mysql_real_escape_string(
                            stripslashes($_FILES['userfile'])));
    $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($fp);
    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    }
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root') or die(mysql_error());
    $db = mysql_select_db('test', $con);
    if ($db) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO upload (name, size, type, content ) " .
                "VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content')";
        mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
        mysql_close();
        echo "<br>File $fileName uploaded<br>";
    } else {
        echo "file upload failed";
    }
}
?>
```

### Download.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Download File From MySQL Database</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; 
              charset=iso-8859-1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root') or die(mysql_error());
        $db = mysql_select_db('test', $con);
        $query = "SELECT id, name FROM upload";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
            echo "Database is empty <br>";
        } else {
            while (list($id, $name) = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                ?>
                <a href="download.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($id); ?>"
                   ><?php echo urlencode($name); ?></a> <br>
                <?php
            }
        }
        mysql_close();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
           <?php
           if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
               $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root') or die(mysql_error());
               $db = mysql_select_db('test', $con);
               $id = $_GET['id'];
               $query = "SELECT name, type, size, content " .
                       "FROM upload WHERE id = '$id'";
               $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
               list($name, $type, $size, $content) = mysql_fetch_array($result);
               header("Content-length: $size");
               header("Content-type: $type");
               header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
               ob_clean();
               flush();
               echo $content;
               mysql_close();
               exit;
           }
           ?>
```

Comment: Try adding `header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');` `header('Content-Description: File Transfer');` and also `readfile($file);` as an example. Maybe just adding `readfile($file);` will suffice. Again `$file` is an example variable. Yet, it mostly likely lies with your headers.

Comment: And instead of `header("Content-length: $size");` try `header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($size));`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Neither of your suggestions make any sense. There's no file, the data is in the database. And the argument to `filesize` is a filename, `$size` is a number.

Comment: *"When the user clicks the link, the file should be downloaded. I've enclosed the script below. But the problem is, when I click the link the content of the file gets displayed instead of getting downloaded."* @Barmar and I didn't come up with `$size`, that's the OP's variable.

Comment: @Fred-ii- But what do you mean by `filesize($size)`? `$size` is the size, not a filename.

Comment: The `header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($size));` is taken from one of my working scripts, which actually reads as `header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_path));` @Barmar - So I was under the impression that the OP should have used the same. And OP has `header("Content-length: $size");`

Comment: I've tried you guys' suggestions. Sorry it didn't work. Can anyone help me out with a code that works... or Suggest me any link to refer...?

Comment: @Fred-ii- It seems like you haven't looked at the guy's script. He isn't storing the upload in a file, he's storing it in a database table. `$size` is one of the fields in the table. There's nothing analogous to your `$file_path` because he's not storing anything in files.

Comment: What do you mean by *"when I click the link the content of the file gets displayed instead of getting downloaded"*? @DhiwaTdG

Comment: I'm confused with the OP's question then. @Barmar - ^-- I just asked the OP now, what he/she means by that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`download.php` is displaying all the HTML at the top even when the user has selected a file to download. You need to put that entire section in an `if` so it doesn't get put at the beginning of the download:

```
if (!isset($_GET['id']) { ?>
    <html>
    ...
    </html>
<?php } else {
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root') or die(mysql_error());
    ... // rest of script
}
```

Comment: I'm definitely going to +1 this. I guess I did misunderstand the question after all. Good show Barmar.